# Azure SQL database working when ran locally but not when published to Azure

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, azure

This has been cracking me up for a few days now and I just can't solve it.

I followed an online tutorial showing you how to connect and use an Azure database using the model first approach within Entity Framework. With this you had to set up database migrations as to update the Azure database when publishing the website to Azure.

I had already created a database on Azure so I thought I would take the approach of using a database first model (also it didn't require migrations to be setup) and used the Entity Framework wizard to create my model. Everything worked perfectly and when I run my MVC website locally it connects to my Azure database and shows the data, etc. However, when I publish the website to the Azure website, for some reason, when I click on tab that uses the controller that gets data from the database, I get an error:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

I have checked my connection strings and they all seem OK and as I said, when I run it locally I can get the data from the Azure database. For some reason, though, I can't get the data once its published.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your connection strings plz?

Comment: <add name="blogModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.blogmodel.csdl|res://*/Models.blogmodel.ssdl|res://*/Models.blogmodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*****.database.windows.net;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: This sounds to me like it might be a deployment issue.  Have you set copy local = true for the EF assemblies.

Comment: You should also insert into the System.Web section of your original Web.config the entry

`<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>`

That will show you a more detailed error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thankyou everyone for your help.

I didn't even think of turning on the copy local however when I checked it it was set to true. So no answer there :(

Next I added the customerrors mode to off to try and get a more detailed description. The error I got was huge and really didn't make much sense so i did the usual thing and googled the error and I found this

[Can anyone spot why I keep getting this error testing the EF 5 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591929/can-anyone-spot-why-i-keep-getting-this-error-testing-the-ef-5-beta)

As soon as I read it i knew this would fix it. I originally setup the project as a .net 4.5 project until I realized that azure websites didn't work with 4.5 yet so I changed it to .net 4 once I uninstalled EF and reinstalled it everything work.

Thanks for all your help. This has been stopping me doing anything for a few days :P