# How to downgrade from EF5 to EF4?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, downgrade

I have an issue, my host only supports NET 4.0 so i cannot properly use EF 5.0, so I would like to downgrade, but i do not know how to do that.

I tried just to change version in web.config but it didn't help, i just get errors, when i run application.

Should i do something special and should i then delete and create whole model again?

I didn't choose any versions when i first started with EF, i just followed a small wizard which generated me a model, but i think the model is of EF5

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly you are going to downgrade? EF5 does work on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 4.0 is ok. Dont use EF 4.0 because its not about EF version. Just change the target framework to .NET 4.0 of application and dependent libraries. After that you probably going to get some errors. Uninstall and install your entity framework dll from nuget. Because of this:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Then you should recreate your model again. Because some of classes may cause errors which are comes with 4.5 Framework like spatial location...

Comment: package? to what section i should add it?

Comment: packages.config file in your solution. you are using nuget, right?

Comment: oh right ))) sorry, didn't know that. So then i just recreate everything and correct classes should be generated?

Comment: and still i have this issue: Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'. on a server :(

Comment: can you send code. is it runtime or compile error. You probably didnt change one of your dependent library to .net4.0 check this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591929/can-anyone-spot-why-i-keep-getting-this-error-testing-the-ef-5-beta)