# ..Net MVC4 Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developed a website using VS Express for Web 2012 with target framework .NET framework 4.0

I am adding a controller using entity framework and i run well in my local computer.

However when i upload it to my hosting, i got this error:

Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'.

In my web.config it show that the reference use is Entity Framework 5.0

Do i need to change it to Entity Framework 4.0 (since maybe my hosting doesn't support version 5.0)?

How to update the reference? I am new to .NET MVC and kinda confuse with NuGet things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to update your EF4 to new version

Comment: try this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591929/can-anyone-spot-why-i-keep-getting-this-error-testing-the-ef-5-beta

Comment: Hi E A, it's solved using similar method as explained in the link you provide

i remove the the reference using Manage NuGet package and reinstalled it again. and make sure my web.config update into something like this:

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>